# HighCharts is only displaying the Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been working through this HighCharts example all day and haven't been able to make it all work.  I'm displaying several data series that are retrieved in a getJSON call.   The chart gets put into its container DIV, but there's no data drawn, and no errors on the javascript console.

I think the problem must be in the JSONP call formatting, but I can't see any problems with it.  The JSONP service is here: `http://199.38.183.107/ow/fludata.php?callback=?`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demonstration of web service</title>
<style type="text/css">
.chart-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js">       </script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script>

$(function () {
  $.getJSON('http://199.38.183.107/ow/fludata.php?callback=?', function(data){
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'spline'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Weekly influenza infection counts'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Data series show the CDC Regions'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
      month: '%e. %b',
      year: '%b'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of infections reported'
    },
    min: 0
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      marker: {enabled: false},
      turboThreshold: 1000000,
      states: {hover: {enabled: false}}
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
           return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' m';
        }
      },
      series: data,
      credits: { enabled: false }
    }); //container
  }); //getJSON
}); //function
```

Comment: your JSON has several errors, check it here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It's JSONP with a callback to jQuery '?' function.  It woudln't normally parse with JSLint, but maybe this is part of the problem.   EDIT:  I tried your suggestion, converting it to just JSON with no callback, and I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your date/time. You should multiply your times with 1000

Comment: This was also true.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had wrapped the data series, which were properly in curly brackets, with an outer curly bracket.   It should be a square bracket since it's returning an array of objects.   Thanks for the help folks.   So when you need to send multiple series that have multiple parts (date and time, or a start and end range) to Highcharts through JSON, you want:

```
[{name:my1stSeries, data:[[1,2],[3,4],...,[m,n]]},{name:my2ndSeries, data:[[5,6],[7,8],...,[o,p]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the json data from the url may be not in the right format for the High Charts. Try to include the onError function on the getJSON function and check the error.